# How to convert a URL to a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a component which uploads an image to Firebase and then receives the image url, which I then store in MongoDB. The problem is I need to store the url as a string. Unformatted, it gets inserted as an object. This is an example url:

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/.../sample.jpeg?alt=media&token=474da151-d6...
```

I use the JSON.stringify method to convert to a string, which then gives me

```
{"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/.../sample.jpeg?alt":"media","token":"474da151-d6..."}
```

Here, alt=media&token=... has been converted to alt":"media","token":"...

What is best way to return the whole url untouched as a string (without the leading and trailing curly braces as well)? I have used .replace() to remove the curly braces but is there a function/method I should be using to do the whole task simply?

EDIT: Here's some more code:
I pass the url: (it's still a string here according to the console.log)

```
console.log("url: ",url)
await axios.put(`/api/users/${id}`, url).then...
```

However, when we goto /api/users.. the req.body is now an object, and if I use json.stringify the 'alt=media&token=' gets changed

```
case 'PUT':
    try {
        console.log("req body: ",req.body)  // OBJECT
        const stringUrl = JSON.stringify(req.body) // SEE BELOW

"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...?alt":"media","token":"..."}
```

Comment: An URL is a string. What's the problem? Could you show some code?

Comment: try this `window.location.href`

Comment: Hi Ricky, I've edited the question to show some more code. Hi Ian, the URL is being returned as a variable from Firebase.

Comment: But that's not a valid object. The property has no key.

Comment: I think there might be some variable confusion here @MattHeslington -- Would you mind posting the complete code snippet? I'm looking to see where `req` is set here and how this all ties together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `Content-Type` header specified, your put request treats your string as query parameters. That's why it get broken down into key-value pairs.(e.g. `a=b&c=d` becomes `{a:b, c:d}`) You can wrap the URL in a object and send the object in JSON.

```
await axios.put(`/api/users/${id}`, {url},{headers:{Content-Type:"applicatino/json"}}).then...
```

Now you will receive a JSON in the req.body, and the `url` property will be your URL.

P.S. A pure string is technically valid JSON and no need to be wrapped in an object, but not all server implementation accept this. It is safer to send an actual object.